# Data confirmation for coronavirus

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

I have run the below program method, In the python 3.7,

```py
corona_dif.nlargest(15, 'Confirmed')
```

but I got the following errors, can anyone explain to me the solution of the problem awaiting your kind response

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please tell us in detail. What are you doing and which python library are you using. If possible Share some code.

Comment: Please share the output of this code ```print(type(corona_diff))```

Comment: Dear Ahwar, i have run this (corona_dif.nlargest(15,'Confirmed')) to show me the list of 15 countries which are in the top of corona case, i have got the errors which i have uploaded as photo png filr please look there

Comment: Please check the name of the column on which you are running the command.

Answer (score 2):

The key 'Confirmed' you are using in `corona_dif.nlargest(15, 'Confirmed)` is wrong. It must be the name of label of a column. KeyError means that the key you are using is wrong.

Please Check the key you are using. It must be the name of label of a column. In your case check spelling and Character case of 'Confirmed' is according to a table's Column name. Maybe it is all in lower case i.e. 'confirmed'.

[image: my solution image]
See in above image My DataFrame has three columns 'x', 'y', 'z'.
In my code when I enter `print(df.nlargest(2, 'x'))` it gives me output, but when I enter wrong key `print(df.nlargest(1, 'xy'))` then it gives error same as yours.

If you have any confusion, Please mention in the comments. I would be very happy in giving you solutions.

Comment: Yess Dear Ahwar! , I follow your instruction, I found there is a problem with the Culonm name

Comment: If this answer solved the problem then mark it accepted by clicking the green tick button in the left of the answer.